# jQuery .index() returns wrong number

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I had this problem where the jQuery .index() method returned a wrong index, more precisely the correct index + 1.
It's not like there was an invisible element that I'm not aware of, as the following line gives me a 'false'.

```
alert(element.parent().find('.user').get(element.index('.user')) == element[0]);
```

Note that `element` is a jQuery object. I thought this line should by definition always alert 'true'. Did I just misinterpret the definition of the method find or why would this be the case?

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: looks fine at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r2b76/2/

Comment: it will work fine if all the `.user` elements are within in the same parent...

Comment: this fails http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r2b76/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Not all .user elements are in the same parent. So this is the issue? How can I match only those with the same parent?

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: I have several lists of users. Now I can drag one user from a list to another. I want to know, to which position (index) in the new list the user has been dragged.

Comment: if you want the new index within the parent of the element then `element.parent().find('.user').index(element)` will give the numerical index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see what you are looking for is

```
var index = element.parent().find('.user').index(element);
```